# how to display a firebase collection with react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

How to display a collection with Firebase. I tried to display a return but it doesn't work so I tried to integrate my arrays in another array except that it rempis it by

Now I get my values in my foreach:

[image]

Now I don't get my values in my foreach:

[image]

Comment: on line 7 why are you having a boolean value as a string `"false"` ? remove the quotes and just write `false`

Comment: also, why your code is not working is because you have a promise. So your line 9 is waiting until `snapShot` is done, but your line 19 is not. If you want your data to be available you need to set the state inside of your promise resolve so after line 16 then you save save the state.

Comment: also you need to think of scope since you are declaring snapshot on line 7 and then you name your value as `snapshot`, avoid doing that.

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Also, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Then, take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
snapshot.then(snap => {
    const tableau = []
    snap.forEach(doc => {
     tableau.push({id: doc.id, ... doc.data()})
    })
    // set state here
    // setTableauData([...tableau])
})
```